# How can I extract URLs from JSON data?

Tags: perl, json

I've a text document from which I want to extract URLs and place them in a new text file. How can I do that in Perl? A sample of the text file is here:

> {"type":"TabGroupsManager:GroupData","id":65,"name":"XML
>   Schema
>   Editor","image":"http://www.altova.com/favicon.ico","disableAutoRename":false,"titleList":"XML
>   Schema Editor\u000aAltova XMLSpy Code
>   Generation\u000aOnline Video
>   Demos\u000aScheduled Data Exchange
>   Case Study\u000aXML Editor\u000aAltova
>   XMLSpy 2011\u000aXML Schema Management
>   Tool\u000a","tabs":["{\"entries\":[{\"url\":\"http://www.altova.com/xmlspy/xml-schema-editor.html\",\"title\":\"XML
>   Schema
>   Editor\",\"ID\":1442422751,\"referrer\":\"http://www.altova.com/xmlspy/xml-editing.html\",\"scroll\":\"0,0\",\"formdata\":{\"#q\":\"\"}}],\"index\":1,\"attributes\":{\"image\":\"http://www.altova.com/favicon.ico\"},\"extData\":{\"TabGroupsManagerGroupId\":\"65\",\"TabGroupsManagerGroupName\":\"XML
>   Schema
>   Editor\"},\"_formDataSaved\":true}","{\"entries\":[{\"url\":\"http://www.altova.com/xmlspy/xml-code-generation.html\",\"title\":\"Altova
>   XMLSpy Code
>   Generation\",\"ID\":1442423118,\"referrer\":\"http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=GR1&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-GB%3Aofficial&q=altova+derive+schema+from+xml&aq=f&aqi=m1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=\",\"scroll\":\"0,0\",\"formdata\":{\"#q\":\"\"}}],\"index\":1,\"attributes\":{\"image\":\"http://www.altova.com/favicon.ico\"},\"extData\":{\"TabGroupsManagerGroupId\":\"65\",\"TabGroupsManagerGroupName\":\"XML
>   Schema
>   Editor\"},\"_formDataSaved\":true}","{\"entries\":[{\"url\":\"http://www.altova.com/videos.asp?type=0&video=xmlspy\",\"title\":\"Online
>   Video
>   Demos\",\"ID\":1442423184,\"referrer\":\"http://www.altova.com/xmlspy/xml-code-generation.html\",\"scroll\":\"0,0\",\"formdata\":{\"#q\":\"\"}}],\"index\":1,\"attributes\":{\"image\":\"http://www.altova.com/favicon.ico\"},\"extData\":{\"TabGroupsManagerGroupId\":\"65\",\"TabGroupsManagerGroupName\":\"XML
>   Schema
>   Editor\"},\"_formDataSaved\":true}","{\"entries\":[{\"url\":\"http://www.altova.com/solutions/exchange_ratecasestudy.html\",\"title\":\"Scheduled
>   Data Exchange Case
>   Study\",\"ID\":2618,\"formdata\":{\"#q\":\"\"},\"scroll\":\"0,1369\"}],\"index\":1,\"attributes\":{\"image\":\"http://www.altova.com/favicon.ico\"},\"extData\":{\"TabGroupsManagerGroupId\":\"65\",\"TabGroupsManagerGroupName\":\"XML
>   Schema
>   Editor\"},\"_formDataSaved\":true}","{\"entries\":[{\"url\":\"http://www.altova.com/xml-editor/\",\"title\":\"XML
>   Editor\",\"ID\":2620,\"formdata\":{\"#q\":\"\"},\"scroll\":\"0,0\"}],\"index\":1,\"attributes\":{\"image\":\"http://www.altova.com/favicon.ico\"},\"extData\":{\"TabGroupsManagerGroupId\":\"65\",\"TabGroupsManagerGroupName\":\"XML
>   Schema
>   Editor\"},\"_formDataSaved\":true}","{\"entries\":[{\"url\":\"http://manual.altova.com/XMLSpy/spystandard/index.html?xmlschemasstd.htm\",\"title\":\"Altova
>   XMLSpy
>   2011\",\"ID\":2622,\"children\":[{\"url\":\"http://manual.altova.com/XMLSpy/spystandard/xmlspy_content_dyn.html\",\"title\":\"Altova XMLSpy
>   2011\",\"ID\":2623,\"referrer\":\"http://manual.altova.com/XMLSpy/spystandard/index.html?xmlschemasstd.htm\",\"scroll\":\"0,0\"},{\"url\":\"http://manual.altova.com/XMLSpy/spystandard/xmlschemasstd.htm\",\"title\":\"XML
>   Schemas\",\"ID\":2624,\"referrer\":\"http://manual.altova.com/XMLSpy/spystandard/index.html?xmlschemasstd.htm\",\"scroll\":\"0,260\"}],\"scroll\":\"0,0\"}],\"index\":1,\"attributes\":{},\"extData\":{\"TabGroupsManagerGroupId\":\"65\",\"TabGroupsManagerGroupName\":\"XML
>   Schema
>   Editor\"},\"_formDataSaved\":true}","{\"entries\":[{\"url\":\"http://www.altova.com/schemaagent.html\",\"title\":\"XML
>   Schema Management
>   Tool\",\"ID\":2626,\"formdata\":{\"#q\":\"\"},\"scroll\":\"0,171\"}],\"index\":1,\"attributes\":{\"image\":\"http://www.altova.com/favicon.ico\"},\"extData\":{\"TabGroupsManagerGroupId\":\"65\",\"TabGroupsManagerGroupName\":\"XML
>   Schema
>   Editor\"},\"_formDataSaved\":true}"]}

From that I want to create a text file like:

```
http://www.altova.com/xmlspy/xml-schema-editor.html
http://www.altova.com/xmlspy/xml-code-generation.html
```

Comment: that is JSON you can use the perl JSON module available at http://search.cpan.org

Comment: Any general purpose URL extraction should use the module [`URI::Find`](http://p3rl.org/URI::Find).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since that appears to be a JSON file rather than a plain text file, use one of the [JSON modules on CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?JSON::Any). This is slightly complicated by the fact that you appear to have data encoded as JSON then stored as strings in a larger object which has then been converted to JSON — so you will have to parse the file, extract the strings, parse them as JSON in turn and then extract the URIs from them.

Comment: Oh..thanks a lot..I got a bunch of big log files from a machine crash and thanks to you experts who could read machine txt and say this is json!!

Comment: @David..if the given text i quoted was a .txt file, would you tell me the script to your solution?

Answer (score 2):

if Perl is not a must ,

```
$ sed 's|\\||g' file| awk -vRS='"url":' -F"," '{print $1}' | grep -E "http|ftp"
"http://www.altova.com/xmlspy/xml-schema-editor.html"
"http://www.altova.com/xmlspy/xml-code-generation.html"
"http://www.altova.com/videos.asp?type=0&video=xmlspy"
"http://www.altova.com/solutions/exchange_ratecasestudy.html"
"http://www.altova.com/xml-editor/"
"http://manual.altova.com/XMLSpy/spystandard/index.html?xmlschemasstd.htm"
"http://manual.altova.com/XMLSpy/spystandard/xmlspy_content_dyn.html"
"http://manual.altova.com/XMLSpy/spystandard/xmlschemasstd.htm"
"http://www.altova.com/schemaagent.html"
```

Comment: Tried this on a Windows machine with MSYS installed..got an error:  '\\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: on windows, change all the single quotes to double quotes and escape all double quotes inside `awk`,  because cmd.exe sucks